# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

when i run this code in google chrome it dose not work it is just a blank page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> "REACT EXAMPLE"></title>
    <script src="react.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1> "hello, React!"<h1>,
        document.getElementById('container')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: did my answer help Abu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't closed the "h1" tag.

Do like that:

```
 <h1> "hello, React!"</h1>,
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing this in the `body`?

```
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1> "hello, React!"<h1>,
        document.getElementById('container')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
```

this should be outside in your `src/index.js` file:

`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'))`